# how can Stuctured architecture mvc core to Use Automapper in BLL layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have Layers Like BLL ,DAL,Core and Presentation in my mvc Core project and have some ViewModel in Presentation Layer.each DAL,BLL and Presentation Use Cpre layer.and I want put DomainProfile Class that extends Profile in Automapper namespace in BLL Layer.But my Prolem is Here:

```
namespace BLL
{
    public class DomainProfile:Profile
    {
        public DomainProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<createViewModel,Contact>
        }
    }
}
```

createViewModel it nameSpace did not found in BLL Layer..
what do I do?!

Answer (score 0):

If you're mapping something to a presentation layer class, then that logic is *presentation layer* logic, not business layer logic. In other words, the profile should live in a context where it has everything it needs available to it. In this case, that means it should live in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

Your architecture is similar to 3-tier architecture . 
For the data layer (DAL)---Data Access Layer: to add the reference of the entity layer (Entity/Model),

For Business Layer (BLL)---Business Logic Layer: A reference to add, data layer (DAL) and entity layer (Entity/Model).

For the presentation layer (UI) --- User Interface: to add a business layer (BLL) and entity layer reference (Model / Entity)

As Chris said above , your mapping seems to be mainly used for the model render in the presentation layer , so it should be presentation layer logic and putting the DomainProfile Class in the presentation layer may be a better choice.